# Accessing Microsoft Graph APIS without MSAL

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have read the documentation provided about Graph APIs and followed the sample codes to implement APIs with delegated and applications permissions.
But my question is, is there a possibility to implement these APIs(such as creating online meeting) without microsoft identity platform? using my own app identity?

Answer (score 0):

according to the [Authentication and authorization basics for MS Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts) documentation , your app must acquire an access token from the Microsoft identity platform.